# Create a block ui

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, styles

I need to create a block ui for all browser windows. The user can't click. I do this in my app-html

```
<div class="spinner">
    <mat-spinner color="primary" mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet id="content"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and in my style.scss I do:

```
//mat spinner
.mat-progress-spinner circle,
.mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: rgb(203, 29, 21);
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.6) !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

the problem is that I want that the block ui block all page but at the top there are some elements that are covered. the result is :
[image]

But i want something like this:
[image]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Absolute positioning positions the element according to its closest positioned parent. If you want to cover the whole page, I suggest using `position: fixed`.

Comment: @WillAlexander doesn't work the same

Comment: I know it doesn't, that's the point. What are you trying to achieve _exactly_? And in which way does `fixed` positioning not achieve your goal?

Comment: @WillAlexander doesn't change anything

Comment: Ah I see, it was a language thing, my apologies. I understood "Doesn't work the same" as "It works differently" :) so can you please explain the _precise_ behaviour you're looking for? Is it that you _want_ your header to be uncovered?